# Hide/Unhide column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells and I am trying to hide/unhide columns based on their headers. I have used VBA for that.

My table consists of main columns (capital letters) and subcolumns which are values that belong to one main category (lowercase letters). This is a sample of my table.

| A | a | b | c | D | e | f | g | H | i | j |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | a | b | c | D | e | f | g | H | i | j |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |

The first row is not a part of the table. Is just the values of the header columns which will be useful to create the filter. Basically I create a pivot of the values in the first row and then in the VBA code I referece this pivot table and those pivot fields along with range of the values that exist in the first row and the sheet that my table and the pivot table are. The first piece of code exists in the actual sheet I have the pivot and the data table and the second is in a module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    'Run the filter columns macro when the pivot table or slicer is changed
    Select Case Target.Name
        Case "PivotTable1"
            Call m_FilterCol.Filter_Columns("headers", "Report", "Report", "PivotTable1", "PivotFields")
    End Select
End Sub
```

This piece of code exists in the actual spreadsheet and not in a module. The references are "headers " = the range of the headers that are in the first row, "Report"= the actual spreasheet that contains the table, "Report"=where the pivot belong, "PivotTable1", "PivotFields"

```
Sub Filter_Columns(sHeaderRange As String, _
                    sReportSheet As String, _
                    sPivotSheet As String, _
                    sPivotName As String, _
                    sPivotField As String _
                    )
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rCol As Range
    Dim pi As PivotItem
     
    'Unhide all columns
    Worksheets(sReportSheet).Range(sHeaderRange).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    
    'Loop through each cell in the header range and compare to the selected filter item(s).
    'Hide columns that are not selected/filtered out.
    
    For Each c In Worksheets(sReportSheet).Range(sHeaderRange).Cells
        
        'Check if the pivotitem exists
        With Worksheets(sPivotSheet).PivotTables(sPivotName).PivotFields(sPivotField)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set pi = .PivotItems(c.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
            
        'If the pivotitem exists then check if it is visible (filtered)
        If Not pi Is Nothing Then
            If pi.Visible = False Then
            
                'Add excluded items to the range to be hidden
                If rCol Is Nothing Then
                    Set rCol = c
                Else
                    Set rCol = Union(rCol, c)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        
        'Reset the pivotitem
        Set pi = Nothing
        
    Next c
    
    'Hide the columns of the range of excluded pivot items
    If Not rCol Is Nothing Then
        rCol.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If    
End Sub
```

This code basically when I apply a filter in that pivot is searching the value in the range of the values in the first row and when it finds it then it hides all the other columns.

The code works with one single filter. But I want to install 2 filters/slicers. One for the main categories and when I select for example A then it will hide everything except the column with the header A and all the subcolumns of it such as a, b, c. Then the second slicer will filter and only the subcolumns a, b, c. So the end results will to keep the unhided the columns A and all the subcolumns we want to have from the category A.

I dublicate the code i have in the spreadsheet and changed only last reference which is for pivot field (filter). It works for the one filter but not for the other.